# How to safely use new and delete for this situtation

Tags: c++, api, design-patterns, memory, heap-memory

I am trying to make a GUI library. And I wish the following statement valid. Plus the user does not responsible for releasing memory.

```
// Create a GUI context
xGUI::xGUI gui(800, 600);
// gui.objects is a std::map<std::string, IWidget *>
gui.objects["btn"] = new xGUI::Button("Close", 50, 50);
gui.objects["btn2"] = gui.objects["btn"]->clone();
// Block end gui will free all the objects.
```

As you can see, clone is ugly but needed.(Is there any solution?) However this clone will use new to allocate memory in the library. then be free by dtor of xGUI which I wrote in header file. new in the library and delete in the main program... Will it be a problem??

Comment: Use unique_ptr and shared_ptr

Comment: "ugly but needed" Why? What for? `gui.objects["btn2"] = gui.objects["btn2"]->clone();` This call looks strange. Why would you replace an object with its clone?

Comment: Sorry for that typo. gui.objects["btn2"]=gui.objects["btn"]->clone()

Comment: A cloned GUI-object appears questionable to me (a design flaw !?)

Comment: Yap. I wish to clone a button in this way. Is this bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead that using an `std::map<std::string, IWidget*>` think about using a `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<IWidget>>`.

An [`std::unique_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is a special wrapper around an object that will automatically manage the destruction of the object when the `unique_ptr` itself is destroyed. This makes managing memory on object which have a single owner (like it seems in your case) quite trivial.

Comment: I quickly found this solution after I post the question actually. but this force us to use the object with gui.objects. I cannot temporary store the pointers to another variable and use them. gui.objects["btn"].get() can deal with this but ugly again

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pointers, but wrappers that behave similar to reference counting smart pointers and expose the required interface:

```
// Create a GUI context
xGUI::xGUI gui(800, 600);
// gui.objects is a std::map<std::string, IWidget *>
gui.objects["btn"] = xGUI::Button("Close", 50, 50);
gui.objects["btn2"] = gui.objects["btn"].clone();
```

Look ma, no pointers, no memory leaks.

Have a look at this json library, with polymorphic behavior, but without the need for the user to cope with dynamic memory allocation: https://github.com/TorstenRobitzki/Sioux/blob/master/source/json/json.h

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? What is the declaration of gui.objects

Comment: `std::map< std::string, Widget >`with `class Button : public Widget`. Widget then contains a pointer to a  polymorphic implementation that is set by deriving classes via a protected c'tor.

Comment: I got it. I initially doubt that we can store button in widget object. thanks. however clone is still there

Comment: It's hard to choose the best answer for me. I adapt your suggestion and combine unique_ptr for my design.  I marked jack as correct answer because he answer is more direct to the question. many thanks for your big help.